# What's the difference between "service start foobar" and "foobar &"

Tags: services

What is the difference between running a program with service (or systemctl) and just running it with absolute path?

My understanding is that service (or systemctl) run some additional scripts associated with the program. Is my understanding right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service start and systemctl start are tool provided by the init system (upstart and systemd respectively) and as such they start **daemons**, which are very different from regular programms in that they run in the background and the user has little control over them directly. For example the *cupsd* (common unix printing system daemon) must run on a system in the background in order to be able to print. cupsd looks for local printers and listens for network printers. You can't print from libreoffice for example if cupsd isn't running.

You can't start daemons like normal programms of normal programms like daemons, i.e. you can't start firefox with service start or cupsd with "cupsd &".